# mysql Schedule Event every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have the following script. The scripts runs but what i want is for it to run every 5 minutes following the wall clock time.  Meaning it should run at 5, 10, 15 ... following the wall clock time at 5 minitues interval.  What I can gauge for the result of the run is that the time is 10 - 30 seconds off.  Is there a way to get it closer to the 5 minutues mark?.  Thanks.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` 
EVENT `run_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2016-04-06 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO CALL my_procedure
```

Comment: Does your server have correct time? Is it running NTP to keep time sync?

Comment: In terms of programming, no, you cannot do anything further with the event. Operations wise you may have some wriggle room. However, if the timing is that critical that you noted it being 10-30 secs off, then you may want to reconsider what you are using as the scheduler. When I see events happening every 5 minutes, then I always ask the question: is the event needed at all?

Comment: The system time is in sync.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your configuration seems correct.  The timing of events is not *extremely* precise, but it is *reasonably* precise -- enough that it shouldn't be half a minute off.

One interesting hack for event troubleshooting is to throw a warning from within the event.  Since there is no client to which the warning can be sent, the warning is written to the MySQL error log.  This should work in MySQL 5.5 and up:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS run_event $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` 
EVENT `run_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2016-04-06 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'run_event started';
  CALL my_procedure;
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'run_event finished';
END $$
```

It's been a while since I used this, but I *believe* the warnings will be written to the error log immediately, and not buffered until the event is finished.

Comment: @AlbertK, I assume this helped you find the problem?  What was the issue?