# mysql duplicate rows delete in big data

Tags: mysql, bigdata, delete-row

I have mysql delete query for duplicated rows.

```
DELETE DupRows.*
                FROM myData AS DupRows
                   INNER JOIN ( 
                      SELECT MIN(ID) AS minId, ondate, symbol
                      FROM myData
                      GROUP BY ondate, symbol
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   ) AS SaveRows ON SaveRows.ondate = DupRows.ondate AND SaveRows.symbol = DupRows.symbol
                      AND SaveRows.minId <> DupRows.ID;
```

But myData table will have now 500000 over rows and will be soon x 100 rows. and when i works this query will be many time or maybe don't work.

So I want to add cron jobs and i want to work this query every 1 hours and wants to query only 1 hours before adden rows.

> How can i add this feature in my query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stop what you are doing!  Change the schema to *prevent* dup rows.  *Then* get rid of the dups.  Only *then* continue receiving data.

What percentage of the table is dups?  If it is a large pct, then

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE myData;
ALTER TABLE new ADD UNIQUE (ondate, symbol);  -- Is this what you need?
INSERT IGNORE INTO new (id, ondate, symbol)
    SELECT MIN(id), ondate, symbol FROM myData
        GROUP BY    ondate, symbol;
RENAME TABLE myData TO old,
             new TO myData;
DROP TABLE old;
```

If you have more than those 3 columns, it messier.

If it is a small pct, then some messy DELETE will work faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysql events which you can trigger automatically in every one hour. It will work like a cron job for you where you can execute your delete query. For events, you can refer to below links:

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html
2. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/
3. [mysql Schedule Event every 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097193/mysql-schedule-event-every-5-minutes)

Hope it may help you to finalize your approach.